# How to Concatenate two dataframes in impala

Tags: dataframe, concatenation, impala

I'm looking for the synthax to concatenate two dataframes in IMPALA.
I want to avoid that operation in R because i have to import the dataframes in R.

Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 0):

select * from (
select * from A
union all
select * from B) temp